# Remove last letter 4 times, get a real word each time, starting word is a car model

Tags: word, knowledge, english

The best I tried so far:

Ford Explorer

Explore

Explor - not real

Explo - not real

Expl - not real

Comment: It's totally tangential, but I thought I'd check: "composers" seems to admit the longest sequence. It depends on "compo" and "compos" both being words, which are pretty obscure.

Comment: Is this your own puzzle, or did you get it from somewhere else?

Comment: Do you have some way to identify a correct or best answer?

Comment: I think this is an open-ended question. There is no 'correct' solution and minimization questions like these tend to have a lot of answers. Please do not post these, and have one with a verifiably correct answer. Therefore I am marking this as too broad. If anyone disagrees, I'd like to see their take on it.

Comment: Agree with @Duck, per the [meta consensus](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6617/57742). To OP: unless you can add additional specifications to help narrow down possible solutions, this question will likely be closed, unfortunately

Answer (score 19):

How about

> Nissan Maxima

Because

> Maxim
>  Maxi (long skirt)
>  Max
>  Ma

Answer (score 17):

How about

> Ford Ranger

Because

> Range
>  Rang
>  Ran
>  Ra

Comment: You can also go to r, the definition is the 18th letter of the alphabet.

Comment: @Duck - True, and that could be applied to basically every answer.

Comment: @Duck R is a letter, not a word. The puzzle is looking for "a real word".

Comment: @JeffC https://www.dictionary.com/browse/r?s=t

Answer (score 5):

How about

> Ford Pinto

Because:

> Pinto
>  Pint
>  Pin
>  Pi
>  P

If you count proper nouns (names):

> Ferrari Mondial

Because:

> Mondial
>  Mondia - Swiss bicycle company
>  Mondi - Paper & Packaging company
>  Mond - a Nickel or Chemical company, or a river
>  Mon - several places, or an old Japanese currency

Or, depending on an atomic abbreviation or an obscure Asian name:

> Fiat Punto

Because:

> Punto
>  Punt - to kick something
>  Pun - joke involving a play on words
>  Pu - see above
>  P - 16th letter of the alphabet

I think these are dredging the bottom of the bucket, but thought I'd list them just the same.

Answer (score 4):

> Model T
>  Model
>  Mode
>  Mod
>  Mo
>  M

Comment: This works with any car that starts that way, and there are a few.

Answer (score 3):

Misread the question but:

> Antes: Multiple bets, also a Slavic tribe
>  Ante: A bet
>  Ant: An insect
>  An: One
>  A: Ford Model A